# Releasing memory in smart pointer

Tags: c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

When we are using dynamically allocated memory, the usefulness of the `delete` command is obvious - we need to let our program know that the memory at the pointer is no longer needed and can be repurposed.

Smart pointers in C++11 (e.g. `unique_ptr`) have a member function seemingly used for a similar purpose: `release()`. I thought the point of using smart pointers was to *avoid* having to manually handle the release of memory. Why is the `release()` function provided when, in this context, it seems pointless?

(pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr::release` is not equivalent to calling `delete` on the managed pointer. `unique_ptr`s are used when you want a sole entity owning a heap-allocated object. `unique_ptr::release` relinquishes ownership and returns the raw pointer. There might be instances when you no longer want the `unique_ptr` to own the managed data and yet not destroy the object - maybe you want to call a legacy API which takes a plain pointer and assumes ownership of it. Or perhaps you want your interface receive a `unique_ptr` but have many `shared_ptr`s having access to it in the implementation. So, the implementation would `release` from the `unique_ptr` and transfer ownership to one or more `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Well put - being somewhat new to C++ I've only used smart pointers in applications where they never pass off their contents and release memory if and only if they go out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

`unique_ptr` only automatically releases memory when it goes out of scope or is assigned a new pointer, but you might want to release the memory before that (the most obvious reason would be optimizing memory usage).